# script ffmpeg small size but quality good 480p for youtube

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a question.
please give the ffmpeg script to convert to 480p, good quality and very small size. do you know? Please let me know

Comment: Some good examples here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube Note their suggestion to encode at the highest possible quality as YouTube will re-encode your video anyway...